# Extract data locations from map

Tags: json, vba, google-maps, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

I want to extract data from a map then get and store the locations all charging station in a specific state. (eg: https://www.plugshare.com/)

How can this be done? I don't mind using any programming language but which one is the best one for this application?

Answer (score 4):

You can retrieve the data directly from https://www.plugshare.com with XHRs. You have to look into a little how does a website work to scrape the data. For any dynamically loaded data you just inspect XHRs the webpage does, find the one containing the relevant data, make the same XHR (either site provides API or not) and parse response. Navigate the page e. g. in Chrome, then open Developer Tools window (<kbd>F12</kbd>), Network tab, reload <kbd>F5</kbd> the page and examine XHRs in the list.

There is one of the requests to URL `https://www.plugshare.com/api/locations/region?...` that returns latitude, longitude and other info for charging stations in a rectangle viewport area with specified coordinates. You can find URL, query parameters and some necessary headers as shown below:

[image: request]

Response is in JSON format:

[image: response]

You need to add basic authorization header to request. To retrieve the credentials go to Sources tab, add XHR Breakpoint for URL contains `https://www.plugshare.com/api/locations/region`, reload <kbd>F5</kbd> the page, when the page is paused on XHR, follow the Call Stack frame by frame:

[image: xhr breakpoint]

Skip any `NREUM` and `nrWrapper` objects that are the part of [New Relic](https://newrelic.com/) functionality. Click pretty-print <kbd>{}</kbd> to format source. Search e. g. `Basic`, `Authorization` or `setRequestHeader` in the sources, for that particular case first match is found in `https://www.plugshare.com/js/main.js?_=1`:

[image: setRequestHeader]

Click a station on the map and you get one more XHR appeared with URL like `https://www.plugshare.com/api/locations/[id]` with detailed information for that station, as shown below:

[image: request detailed]

Response is in JSON format also:

[image: response detailed]

Also you may get data for stations from URL like `https://www.plugshare.com/api/stations/[id]`.

You may use the below VBA code to retrieve info as described above. **Import [JSON.bas](https://github.com/omegastripes/VBA-JSON-parser) module into the VBA project for JSON processing.**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test_www_plugshare_com()

    Const Transposed = False ' Output option
    Const Detailed = True ' Scrape option

    Dim sResponse As String
    Dim aQryHds()
    Dim oQuery As Object
    Dim sQuery As String
    Dim vRegionJSON
    Dim sState As String
    Dim aResult()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim vLocationJSON
    Dim aRows()
    Dim aHeader()

    ' Retrieve auth token
    XmlHttpRequest "GET", "https://www.plugshare.com/js/main.js?_=1", "", "", "", sResponse
    With RegExMatches(sResponse, "var s\=""(Basic [^""]*)"";")  ' var s="Basic *";
        If .Count > 0 Then
            aQryHds = Array( _
                Array("Authorization", .Item(0).SubMatches(0)), _
                Array("Accept", "application/json") _
            )
        Else
            MsgBox "Can't retrieve auth token"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    ' Set query parameters
    Set oQuery = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With oQuery
        .Add "minimal", "1"
        .Add "count", "500"
        .Add "latitude", "19.697593650121235"
        .Add "longitude", "-155.06529816792295"
        .Add "spanLng", "0.274658203125"
        .Add "spanLat", "0.11878815323507652"
        .Add "access", "1,3"
        .Add "outlets", "[{""connector"":1},{""connector"":2},{""connector"":3},{""connector"":4},{""connector"":5},{""connector"":6,""power"":0},{""connector"":6,""power"":1},{""connector"":7},{""connector"":8},{""connector"":9},{""connector"":10},{""connector"":11},{""connector"":12},{""connector"":13},{""connector"":14},{""connector"":15}]"
        .Add "fast", "add"
    End With
    sQuery = EncodeQueryParams(oQuery)
    ' Retrieve a list of stations for the viewport
    XmlHttpRequest "GET", "https://www.plugshare.com/api/locations/region?" & sQuery, aQryHds, "", "", sResponse
    ' Parse JSON response
    JSON.Parse sResponse, vRegionJSON, sState
    If sState <> "Array" Then
        MsgBox "Invalid JSON response"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ' Populate result array
    ReDim aResult(UBound(vRegionJSON))
    ' Extract selected properties from parsed JSON
    For i = 0 To UBound(aResult)
        Set aResult(i) = ExtractKeys(vRegionJSON(i), Array("id", "name", "latitude", "longitude"))
        DoEvents
    Next
    If Detailed Then
        ' Populate result array with detailed info for each location
        For i = 0 To UBound(aResult)
            ' Retrieve detailed info for each location
            XmlHttpRequest "GET", "https://www.plugshare.com/api/locations/" & aResult(i)("id"), aQryHds, "", "", sResponse
            ' Parse JSON response
            JSON.Parse sResponse, vLocationJSON, sState
            If sState = "Object" Then
                ' Extract selected properties from parsed JSON
                Set aResult(i) = ExtractKeys(vLocationJSON, Array("reverse_geocoded_address", "hours", "phone", "description"), aResult(i))
            End If
            DoEvents
        Next
    End If
    ' Convert resulting array to arrays for output
    JSON.ToArray aResult, aRows, aHeader
    ' Output
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        .Cells.Delete
        If Transposed Then
            Output2DArray .Cells(1, 1), WorksheetFunction.Transpose(aHeader)
            Output2DArray .Cells(1, 2), WorksheetFunction.Transpose(aRows)
        Else
            OutputArray .Cells(1, 1), aHeader
            Output2DArray .Cells(2, 1), aRows
        End If
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With
    MsgBox "Completed"

End Sub

Sub XmlHttpRequest(sMethod As String, sUrl As String, arrSetHeaders, sFormData, sRespHeaders As String, sContent As String)

    Dim arrHeader

    'With CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    '    .SetOption 2, 13056 ' SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_ALL_SERVER_ERRORS
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open sMethod, sUrl, False
        If IsArray(arrSetHeaders) Then
            For Each arrHeader In arrSetHeaders
                .SetRequestHeader arrHeader(0), arrHeader(1)
            Next
        End If
        .send sFormData
        sRespHeaders = .GetAllResponseHeaders
        sContent = .responseText
    End With

End Sub

Function RegExMatches(sText, sPattern, Optional bGlobal = True, Optional bMultiLine = True, Optional bIgnoreCase = True) As Object

    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = bGlobal
        .MultiLine = bMultiLine
        .IgnoreCase = bIgnoreCase
        .Pattern = sPattern
        Set RegExMatches = .Execute(sText)
    End With

End Function

Function EncodeQueryParams(oParams As Object) As String

    Dim aParams
    Dim i As Long

    aParams = oParams.Keys()
    For i = 0 To UBound(aParams)
        aParams(i) = EncodeUriComponent((aParams(i))) & "=" & EncodeUriComponent((oParams(aParams(i))))
    Next
    EncodeQueryParams = Join(aParams, "&")

End Function

Function EncodeUriComponent(strText As String) As String

    Static objHtmlfile As Object

    If objHtmlfile Is Nothing Then
        Set objHtmlfile = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        objHtmlfile.parentWindow.execScript "function encode(s) {return encodeURIComponent(s)}", "jscript"
    End If
    EncodeUriComponent = objHtmlfile.parentWindow.encode(strText)

End Function

Function ExtractKeys(oSource, aKeys, Optional oTarget = Nothing) As Object

    Dim vKey

    If oTarget Is Nothing Then Set oTarget = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each vKey In aKeys
        If oSource.Exists(vKey) Then
            If IsObject(oSource(vKey)) Then
                Set oTarget(vKey) = oSource(vKey)
            Else
                oTarget(vKey) = oSource(vKey)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Set ExtractKeys = oTarget

End Function

Sub OutputArray(oDstRng As Range, aCells As Variant)

    With oDstRng
        .Parent.Select
        With .Resize(1, UBound(aCells) - LBound(aCells) + 1)
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = aCells
        End With
    End With

End Sub

Sub Output2DArray(oDstRng As Range, aCells As Variant)

    With oDstRng
        .Parent.Select
        With .Resize( _
                UBound(aCells, 1) - LBound(aCells, 1) + 1, _
                UBound(aCells, 2) - LBound(aCells, 2) + 1)
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = aCells
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Change to `Const Detailed = False` if you have a lot of items for output to prevent application hanging, since XHRs are in synchronous mode. The output for me with specified viewport coordinates is as follows:

[image: output]

BTW, the similar approach applied [in other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a2165759%20is%3aanswer%20json.bas).