# Web Scraping - Downloading Zip File

Tags: post, web-scraping, zip

I'm trying to download a bunch of PDF files from a website that come bundled in a zip file with python. To download the zip file, I click a download button that makes a popup appear (I assume this is not important to the problem but I will include it for completeness). Chrome shows this when the download button is pressed and the popup appears:

[image]

[image]

I must then click the download button that's on the popup to actually begin the download. This is what follows:

[image]

I am quite confident that the first request is the only important one. If we look at the headers for this POST Request we see this:

[image]
[image]

All the POST data needed for this request can be scraped from the previous HTML page with the exception of the downloadedZipToken. This token is only generated/added to the html form after I click the download button on the popup and you can see that it's returned to me in the response header as a cookie.

So to summarize. In order to have a python script download the zip file for me I believe I have to mimic this POST request which I haven't been able to do because the zip token is not initially accessible. I apologize if this was confusing. Please let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Try to search the token in sources like in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43770298/2165759). The example just shows the approach.

Comment: @omegastripes Thanks! I looked at the examples and sent you an email with some specific questions if you have time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The downloadZipToken POST data that I wasn't able to find in my original question turns out to be a unix timestamp which makes a lot more sense as to why I couldn't find it in the HTML source. I assume it's generated by some JS script once the POST request is sent. To write my python code I just generated a unix timestamp with

```
timeStamp = math.ceil(time.time()*1000)
```